# Issue with: Upload image Database Laravel "c:\xampp\tmp\php.tmp"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm confused again, if im trying to upload a image im my database. The name of the image is given with a tmp file like this "C:\xampp\tmp\phpB001.tmp". What is the solution to this Issue.

**Controller**: AdminLeistungController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->_validate($request);
        $data['creator_id'] = auth()->user()->id;

        if($request->hasfile('image')){
            $fileameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = pathinfo($fileameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('uploads/leistungen', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }

        Leistungen::create($data);

        return redirect(route('admin.leistung.index'))->withSuccess('Successfully');
    }

private function _validate($request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'title' => 'required',
            'article' => 'required|min:3',
            'seo_title' => 'required',
            'seo_description' => 'required',
            'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png|max:1014',
        ];

        return $this->validate($request, $rules);
    }

public function update(Request $request, Leistungen $leistung)
    {
        $data = $this->_validate($request);
        $leistung->update($data);

        return redirect(route('admin.leistung.index'))->withSuccess('Successfully');
    }
```

**Controller**: create.blade.php

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('admin.leistung.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="col-lg-12">
@include('admin.leistung._form')
...
```

**Controller**: _form.blade.php

```
<input type="file" id="image" name="image" value="{{old('image') ?? $leistung->image ?? ''}}" class="form-control @if($errors->has('image')) is-invalid @endif">
```

Comment: Are you planning on doing something with the `$fileNameToStore` variable you have set?